# CSRF Guard - Can it protect service call also?

Tags: java, web-services, csrf-protection

I'm implementing CSRF guard in my web application. I have done all the required configuration and I can see token getting generated/injected into the request header.

Let me tell you application's architecture a bit, I have JSP pages which makes call to services using Ajax to get the data and display in the UI.

My question here is **"Can we protect service calls also with CSRF guard?"** If it is possible then how can I do this because it is not going to `CsrfGuardFilter.java` class when I'm debugging the execution.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please add some details about your application flows.

Comment: I have already mentioned the basic architecture of the application and I believe this much information will be enough for this problem. If you want to know something specific then let me know.?

Comment: I think service calls through ajax from javascript from a jsp page also a type of normal web request.For example in our application we have filter based on url extension like .do url's for normal requestes and .ajax for ajax requests.Based on the extension we will apply different filters for a request.

Comment: @webcoder sorry buddy but you haven't understand the question properly. Its not about differentiating normal or ajax request.